# python - replace string entry with a dictionary entry

Tags: python, regex, templates, string-formatting

I have a string like
    `'MATERIAL 4 {clad-den} {clad-temp} 2'`,
and I want to replace entries like
    `{clad-den}`, `{clad-temp}`
(in figure brackets) with corresponding values from a dictionary, which have the same key, as enclosed in brackets - like
    `data['clad-den']`
to receive a string like:
    `'MATERIAL 4 6.55 578.0 2'`.
How can I do that?

I have some thoughts directed at `re.sub`. Something like:
    `re.sub(('{\S+}'),data[('\S+')],string)`,
but I don't know how to make it use the same key as it's replacing each time.

Comment: `'MATERIAL 4 {clad-den} {clad-temp} 2'.format_map(your_dict)`

Comment: Please read the guidelines to see how to ask a good question. Also edit your post and format it properly so that it's more readable.

Comment: @Neeku: The question isn't all that bad, really. The OP did include an attempt at using regular expressions but did not know how to translate that to working code. Formatting is easy to apply and help with.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The down-vote was for the bad/nonexistent formatting. I didn't attempt to edit it myself, so that the OP would try doing it and learn how to do so. (: Down-vote removed now, still 2 more are sitting there!

Comment: @Neeku: Really, formatting can be tricky. For *new users* it is far more helpful to do a quick edit. For Python source code with no or broken indentation that's not always possible, but *just formatting issues* does not make a question not useful or showing a lack of research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) out of the box for this:

```
'MATERIAL 4 {clad-den} {clad-temp} 2'.format(**data)
```

This will look up `clad-den` and `clad-temp` as keys in the `data` dictionary:

```
>>> data = {'clad-den': 6.55, 'clad-temp': 578.0}
>>> 'MATERIAL 4 {clad-den} {clad-temp} 2'.format(**data)
'MATERIAL 4 6.55 578.0 2'
```

You can do it with `re.sub()` too, using a function for the replacement parameter:

```
re.sub(r'{([^{}]+)}', lambda m: str(data[m.group(1)]), template_text)
```

but this doesn't offer the same flexibility and power that string formatting can offer.

Comment: wow. looks witty. I think I am lucky with that curly brackets, so I can use str.format()?

Comment: @user3884045: exactly.